# How to make the CalendarView vertical scroll in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How do you change the calendar layout to vertical mode?
I am using CalendarView within ScrollView. Now I am implementing the scroll up and down view in **Vertical scroll** for getting previous or next months calendar.

I am trying to implement like below CalendarView.....

https://ibb.co/TLDFbrm "CalendarView Like that"
Please help me I am in trouble.

```
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CalendarView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                </CalendarView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Any ideas? Let me know! thanks...

Comment: I don't think the old (and new) native picker supports that; this is what Material design has to offer: https://material.io/design/components/pickers.html#mobile-pickers

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below code.

**Activity_main.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context="ganeshannt.calendarview.MainActivity">  

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/date"  
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="51dp"  
        android:text="Date"  
        android:textAlignment="center"  
        android:textSize="45dp"  
        android:visibility="visible"  
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"  
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.219" />  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/btngocalendar"  
        android:layout_width="266dp"  
        android:layout_height="47dp"  
        android:text="Go to calendar"  
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="47dp"  
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />  

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Create new calendar_layout.xml file (File ⇒ New ⇒Activity⇒Empty_activity).

Go to calendar_layout.xml then click the text bottom. 
This xml file contains the designing code for android app,Into the calendar_layout.xml copy and paste the below code

**calendar_layout.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent">  

<CalendarView  
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Create new CalendarActivity.java file (File ⇒ New ⇒Java class).

Into the CalendarActivity.java copy and paste the below code.java programming is the backend language for android. Do not replace your package name otherwise app will not run.

**CalendarActivity.java code**

```
package ganeshannt.calendarview;  

import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;  
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.widget.CalendarView;  



public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    private  static final String TAG = "CalendarActivity";  
    private CalendarView mCalendarView;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar_layout);  
        mCalendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);  
        mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView CalendarView, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {  
              String date = year + "/" + month + "/"+ dayOfMonth ;  
                Log.d(TAG, "onSelectedDayChange: yyyy/mm/dd:" + date);  
                Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this,MainActivity.class);  
                intent.putExtra("date",date);  
                startActivity(intent);  

            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It's not working. I am trying a vertical calendar scroll view.

Comment: Sorry for that you can try this github link it will surely help you @RishiRaj https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview